# Trouble using QSerialport in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, git, qt, ubuntu

I made a full application in QT creator on my mac (tested and working) and now need to move the source code to my Ubuntu machine and recompile it in QT creator in ubuntu.

This problem is as soon as the project opens I get this error in the "general messages" log

`Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: serialport`

So I assumed that QSerialport isn't included in the ubuntu release of QT creator.

I tried to get it myself using these terminal commands I got from a tutorial for installing QSerialport (I don't know linux at all and this is my first time using it).

`git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtserialport.git`

`cd qtserialport`

`git checkout qt5.x.y`
This is where i get stuck.  I have tried substituting 'x' and 'y' for every number and its returns that no such file can be found.

Have I made some simple mistake?  Has anyone out there had to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

If anyone else has this problem open "Maintain QT" (which can be found in the installation folder).  Select "Add or remove components".  In the version of QT you have installed there is a sub-heading called "Source components" and within the "Add ons" category you need to select Qserialport".  Then just hit next and install.

Everything worked fine after this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your self:

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qtserialport.git
mkdir qtserialport-build
cd qtserialport-build
qmake ../qtserialport/qtserialport.pro
sudo make install
```

Comment: Hey thanks for trying to help.  The sudo make install command gave this error.

`compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [.obj/qserialport.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mattpamenter/qtserialport-build/src/serialport'
make[1]: *** [sub-serialport-install_subtargets] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mattpamenter/qtserialport-build/src'
make: *** [sub-src-install_subtargets] Error 2`

Comment: Try "make" only before "sudo make install"

Comment: This also failed with the same message.

Comment: Its also worth noting that I have now tried this on a Ubuntu virtual machine on my mac.  And a normally installed ubuntu on a mini pc.  Same errors.

Comment: On linux systems you need libudev to build this, install this by:
"apt-get install libudev-dev"
if not work please post the full build error.

Comment: Installing the library worked.  "make" returned the same error (its really long so is will stretch over several comments). posting it now.

Comment: mattpamenter@ubuntu:~/qtserialport-build$ make
cd src/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /home/mattpamenter/qtserialport/src/src.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile 
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/mattpamenter/qtserialport-build/src'
cd serialport/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake /home/mattpamenter/qtserialport/src/serialport/serialport.pro -o Makefile ) && make -f Makefile 
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/mattpamenter/qtserialport-build/src/serialport'

Comment: g++ -c -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++0x -fno-exceptions -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIC -DQT_NO_MTDEV -DQT_BUILD_SERIALPORT_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x050000 -DLINK_LIBUDEV -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_CORE_LIB -

Comment: -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64 -I/home/mattpamenter/qtserialport/src/serialport -I../../include -I../../include/QtSerialPort -I../../include/QtSerialPort/5.6.0 -I../../include/QtSerialPort/5.6.0/QtSerialPort -I/home/mattpamenter/qtserialport/src/serialport -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/5.2.1 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/5.2.1/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt5 -I/usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I.moc -I. -o .obj/qserialport.o /home/mattpamenter/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport.cpp
In file included from /home/mattpamenter/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport.cpp:41:0:

Comment: /home/mattpamenter/qtserialport/src/serialport/qserialport_p.h:52:35: fatal error: private/qringbuffer_p.h: No such file or directory
 #include <private/qringbuffer_p.h>
                                   ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [.obj/qserialport.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mattpamenter/qtserialport-build/src/serialport'
make[1]: *** [sub-serialport-make_first] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mattpamenter/qtserialport-build/src'
make: *** [sub-src-make_first] Error 2
mattpamenter@ubuntu:~/qtserialport-build$ ^C
mattpamenter@ubuntu:~/qtserialport-build$

Comment: This is the relevant msg:  fatal error: private/qringbuffer_p.h: No such file or directory
Solve this by: "apt-get install qtbase5-private-dev"

Comment: That installed correctly.  I then ran make again which gave an even longer error.  (I could send you a screen shot if thats easier?) my email is "mattpamenter@gmail.com"

Answer (score 1):

Listed in the Ubuntu package repo is the `libqt5serialport` package, so it should be available but you may need to install the package manually: http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libqt5serialport5